# How to place if condition based on attribute value within for-each loop

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a loop in xsl and depending upon the attribute value, i want to write some text.

XML is as follows:

```
<ROWS><ROW oid="28439"><EFL eid="8" fid="27672" count="2">
 <MK id="3" val="0"/>
 <MK id="11" val="0578678             "/> </ROW></ROWS>
```

XSL is as follows:

```
<xsl:for-each select="EFL/MK">
         <xsl:value-of select="@id" />: 
        <xsl:value-of select="@val" />
      </xsl:for-each>
```

I want to have the following output:
3:0 **&** 11:057868

**"&"** is needed if there are more than one "**MK**" tags. Count of "MK" tags is available in "**Count**" attribute of "**Row**" tag.

Can you please tell me how to put the following if condition in XSL:

if **Count Atrribute** available in **Row tag** has a value greater than 1 Then
      Display **"&"**
EndIF

Thanks

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a compact solution. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="EFL/MK">
  <xsl:value-of select="@id" />: 
  <xsl:value-of select="@val" />
  <xsl:if test="../@count &gt; 1">
    <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())"><![CDATA[ &  ]]></xsl:if>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: It's very rare that using CDATA is a good idea, and there's no evidence in this case that it's necessary.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="ROWS/ROW">
   <xsl:for-each select="EFL/MK">
    <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat(substring(' &amp; ', 1 div (position() > 1)),
             @id,
             ':',
             @val,
             substring('&#xA;', 1 div (position() = last()))
             )
     "/>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be well-formed):

```
<ROWS>
 <ROW oid="28439">
   <EFL eid="8" fid="27672" count="2">
    <MK id="3" val="0"/>
    <MK id="11" val="0578678"/>
   </EFL>
 </ROW>
</ROWS>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
3:0 & 11:0578678
```